# npm run div gives error in my nextjs project

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, next.js13, vite-reactjs

osama@DESKTOP-02L572R MINGW64 /c/laragon/www/tojjar/frontend (osama-newTask)
$ npm run dev

> tojjar@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stdin')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\amraq\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-13T11_25_11_205Z-debug-0.log

Due to this issue i am unable to run any project that coressponds to npm/nodes, I have uninstalled and reinstalled the nodejs and npm too. Tried npm cache clean --force but got same error, i think is globally because i get this error on all of my projects

Comment: Can you please add code snippet as well to check what is wrong.

Comment: **i don't have error in my code**, the only error is in my _npm_ and _nodejs_, idk where the conflict is but **i also installed its latest versions**, still getting same error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.